# What happens to running code when a viewcontroller changes/disappears in IOS

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, lifecycle

Say I have 2 viewcontrollers controlled by a tab bar controller.  If the first viewcontroller is in the middle of running some code and the user switches to the second view controller via the tab bar controller what happens to the running code?  Does it stop? or keep going in the background.

Comment: Assuming you haven't created a new thread to do any work on, your code will always finish before the tap is registered. Reason - by default view controllers perform code on the main thread. Your tap is registered on the main thread.

Comment: Actually the code can run indefinitly.  I have a timer in my first view controller that runs a block of code to take image and send over network every minute.  I'm curious what would happen if it's in the middle of sending some images over the network and the user switches tab etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing special happens. A tab bar controller retains all of its view controllers at once. Switching from one view controller to another therefore does not threaten the life of the view controller that disappeared.